# How to use singleton data in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I tried to create a singleton to set and get a string between different views:

**globalVar.h:**

```
@interface globalVar : NSObject
{
    NSString *storeID;
}

+ (globalVar *)sharedInstance;
@property  (nonatomic, copy) NSString *storeID;
@end
```

**globalVar.m:**

```
#import "globalVar.h"

@implementation globalVar
@synthesize storeID;

+ (globalVar *)sharedInstance
{
       static globalVar *myInstance = nil;    

    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];        
    }
    return myInstance;
}
@end
```

Now how do I actually use the string? Say I want to set it to "asdf" in one view and load the "asdf" in another view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set it, do something like:

```
[globalVar sharedInstance].storeID = @"asdf";
```

And to use it:

```
NSString *myString = [globalVar sharedInstance].storeID;
```

Comment: for set, i got an error "Receiver type 'globalVar' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setstoreID:"

Comment: @James sorry - I changed my answer to use Objective-C 2.0 accessors.  You must have tried before I made the switch.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change how you create your instance.  Do it like this:

```
+ (GlobalVar *)sharedInstance
{
    static GlobalVar *myInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (nil == myInstance) {
            myInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return myInstance;
}
```

You do *not* want to use `[self class]`, because in this case `self` is already the `globalVar` class.

Second, you should name the class `GlobalVar` with a capital `G`.

Third, you will use it like this:

```
[GlobalVar sharedInstance].storeID = @"STORE123";
NSLog(@"store ID = %@", [GlobalVar sharedInstance].storeID);
```